# How to adjust system volume when in low_latency(set in audio_policy.conf) mode

Tags: low-latency

In driver layer, the max volume parameter can't be set when it's in low_latency mode in audio_policy.conf. The reason to change from deep_buffer mode to low_latency, keypad tone has a delay when the key pressed. Change to low_latency resolve it. Any ideas?